# Origin and usage of "no-yeah" and "yeah-no"

Tags: english

I'm curious to know if there is any history between the usages of "yeah-no" and "no-yeah" in English, and if the usage of the two terms or an equivalent is used in other languages. Also, is there a distinct difference in meaning between the two phrases in terms of usage and context or are they interchangeable? I've noticed a lot of people including myself tend to use both in everyday language. Example usage:

> Person A: I think pizzas are pretty awesome.
>
> Person B: No-yeah, pizzas are definitely awesome.

Comment: "Yeah no" is from Australia, I'm pretty sure it originated there too. I don't think I've really encountered "no yeah".

Comment: see this post on [language log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005523.html)

Comment: Russian has "yes no" which means something like "well, no". This can be a coincidence, though, as there's a particle which sounds exactly like "yes" but has a different meaning. There's a joke about confusing foreigners by answering, literally, "yes no maybe" to a question

Comment: FWIW, in Hebrew *ken lo* "yes no" is fairly common, but I don't recall ever having heard *lo ken* "no yes".

Comment: I've spoken English almost every day of my life and I've never come across this!?

Answer (score 1):

there's also a similar phrase in german and south african. Americans use this a lot, too so I doubt it originated in Australia, but possibly has common origins before that. It might have been studied most in Australian English, but it's very prevalent in the U.S. also.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Once you have earned a few points of reputation you can comment everywhare.